# Could not obtain server certificate chain

Tags: java, centos, ssl-certificate

I have used InstallCert.java file from "http://code.google.com/p/java-use-examples/source/browse/trunk/src/com/aw/ad/util/InstallCert.java" to generate certificate in java 7(which was installed on CentOS 5.9).

After successfully compiled and run the program, I received UnsupportedOperationException when InstallCert tried to handshake with server host. I found a solution to overcome this issue after doing some searches over the web. Please find the change I made on InstallCert.java file.

**Replaced the below line:**
 
*SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket)factory.createSocket(host, port);*

**With this new line:**
*SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket)factory.getDefault().createSocket(host, port);*

After the above change was made, SSLSocket handshake has became successful. But when calling the chain() method of SavingTrustManager instance, it returned a *null* value. Due to this the certificate file was not generated in the working directory.

I appreciate if anyone could help me to overcome this issue and generate the certificate file successfully.

***Note:*** I didn't get any issues in Java 6 but the above issues were occured in Java 7.